# Create JSON response of pandas dataframes clubbed into a dictionary

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have the following flask function where I would like to return a valid json resp

```
   modified_results = modified_results.groupby(['some_type'])
   tempResult = {}
   for groupName, group in modified_results:
        df = group.drop(columns=['some_type'])
        tempResult[groupName] = processHours(df, project_code).to_json(orient='records')
   return jsonify(tempResult)
```

I am getting my response in the format I would like except there are escape characters and the tempResult Dictionary has the whole data frame as one object value to the key label.

How can I club the dictionaroies like this and convert into json:

```
dictObj = {key1:pd.DataFrame(), key2: pd.DataFrame()}
resp = dictObj.to_json()
return resp
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I did get my answer but the to_json silently ignores the index values. This is what I did.

```
modified_results = modified_results.groupby(['some_type'])
newResults = {}
for groupName, group in modified_results:
    df = group.drop(columns=['some_type'])
    newResults[groupName] = processHours(df, project_code)

df_keys = pd.concat(newResults)
return df_keys.to_json(index=True, orient='records')
```

The `index=True` argument has no effect.

The issue seems to be currently open = [Github Open Bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/25513)

Alternate solution is to add the key as a column and filter it after receiving the response (this is not an actual solution) :

```
    modified_results = modified_results.groupby(['some_type'])
    newResults = {}
    for groupName, group in modified_results:
        df = group.drop(columns=['some_type'])
        df = processHours(df, project_code)
        df = df.assign(some_type=[groupName]*len(df))
        newResults[groupName] = df

    resp = pd.concat(newResults)
    return resp.to_json(index=True, orient='records')
```